# 6 digit UTM to DD

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, coordinates, utm

I've done some searching online but I can't find an answer to my question, hence posting here. I have a spreadsheet of UTM coordinates (I think they're UTM) and I need to convert them into DD.

All I have for each location is one 6 digit number with no decimal points - for instance 123456. This is all I have to go on other than the coordinates are all located in South Africa. Should there not be a second 6 or 7 digit number, or how do I get a location from just the one 6 digit number?

Clearly I'm no expert here.

Comment: You need to know which CRS your source coordinates are in. Otherwise you can't convert them properly.

Comment: Can you add some real samples from your spreadsheet? Do you know roughly where (on earth) the points should be located?

Comment: So without knowing the CRS is there no way of converting the coordinate? I have 727997 for eg. All coordinates are in South Africa.

Comment: South Africa exists in *four* UTM zones (33-36). The easting can be in any one of them.

Comment: Northings in South Africa have 7 digits. As Erick states, you must ask your data provider in which coordinate system are your locations. Can you share a sample of them?

Comment: Thanks. The coordinates are in various formats, all to be converted to DD. Some are simply 6 digits like 727997, that’s all there is for the location, others are written 3348S1822E or S34 22 22.6 E16 56 32.5, which makes a bit more sense.

Comment: Some clarification I’ve just received, the 6 digit format (eg 727997) is decimal minutes south to 3dp and decimal minutes east to 3dp. Does this make sense to anyone?

Comment: so is it both lon-lat together? the 316146?

Comment: Yes, I presume so.

Comment: You can share a sample of the data?

Comment: All I have is 316146 as a location in a cell in Excel. What else would help?

Comment: Like this?
316146
Decimal Minutes South 316/60=5.267
Decimal Minutes East 146/60=2.433
That just doesn't seem right.

Comment: Share a small dataset and it's supposed area of location on a map.

Comment: Share a few more examples of the 6 digit coordinates if you can.

Answer (score 1):

(EDIT) It appears the description of the problem has been changed, making my answer sound ridiculous.  Just for clarification, originally the problem was about 6 digits described as decimal minutes South and West, and that's what I answered.

Almost certainly this format assumes some value for Latitude and Longitude in degrees, these are the the decimal minute part of the coordinates.

So for your example, if you are working anywhere in Pretoria, the degree part of Latitude will be 25° S and the degree part of Longitude will be 28° E, so the coordinate represented by 316146 would be 25° 31.6' S, 28° 14.6' E

If all the other coordinates in your table all have the same Latitude degrees value (for example all 25°) and Longitude in degrees (for example 28°), then 25 and 28 are your baseline Lat and Long values are.  If there are a mix of Lat and Long values in the spreadsheet, you need to go back to ask for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You may test several UTM zones (for instance, a pair of coordinates in a northern hemisphere, thus, `+north`) in the following way:

```
for ((utmZone=10;utmZone<20;utmZone++))
do
  echo 631456.83356859628 3816200.7961099017 | proj -f "%.4f" +proj=utm +zone=$utmZone +north +ellps=WGS84 -I
done
```

which gives (ie. different UTM zones):

```
-121.5685       34.4790
-115.5685       34.4790
-109.5685       34.4790
-103.5685       34.4790
-97.5685        34.4790
-91.5685        34.4790
-85.5685        34.4790
-79.5685        34.4790
-73.5685        34.4790
-67.5685        34.4790
```

This works in Linux with the PROJ tool. Hope this helps.